# How to know when PM2 deploy status changes to "error"

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2, pm2-logrotate

Is there a way to notify a developer when the PM2 status of an application is showing "error"?

Comment: You might need to write a script when an error occurs you can send an email to the developers. You can register an error handler in node. I guess pm2 doesn't provide one.

Comment: Also I'm thinking of adding Appmetrics or Promotheuse for better monitoring since pm2 plus is a paid service. Have you implemented any of these for logging or monitoring.

Comment: I am afraid not, but you can use them `Appmetrics` supports `.net core`.

Comment: You can use a third party service like RollBar: https://rollbar.com/ for example.